QGIS - find overlapping areas between polygons and retrieve id per polygon
I'm having trouble understanding how to find overlapping areas between two polygons (using QGIS, but I'm open to coding if it's any easier), and obtain not only the output polygon, but also which polygons does it come from (I have roughly 50 polygons, some overlap and some doesn´t).
An example with polygons A, B, and C:

I want to get the overlap between A-B (without C), A-C (without B), B-C (without A), and A-B-C.
E.g. A-B:

E.g. A-B-C:

I would want an output of :

A polygon for each interaction (e.g.: polygon_A_B, polygon_A_C, etc)

A dataframe which would tell me which polygons are in which interaction, such as:

polygon_id      polygon_1    polygon_2   polygon_3
polygon_A_B     A            B           NA
polygon_A_C     A            C           NA
polygon_A_B_C   A            B           C





@BERA No, they are all in different shapefiles...

Meh... if all where in the same layer, the union tool would do half the work.

@Erik any way also in QGIS of doing that quickly? i.e. merging all the shapefiles

You might look at the SAGA polygon self intersection tool in Processing.


Merge all layers into one
Union the merge output with itself as Input layer, no Overlay layer
Aggregate the output, concatenate the columns, group by $geometry



Tried to find this solution using the field calculator, but the tool is way easier. Neat one.

This works very well, thank you!!

@BERA I actually just realised that, in the 2nd step (Union), if I don't add anything in the "Overlay layer", I get this error: "Feature could not be written to (...): Could not add feature with geometry type MultiLineString to layer of type MultiPolygon
Could not write feature". If I add the "Merged" output as "Overlay layer", it works but I only get the overlaps between two polygons and not three (as you have, and I should have too). I guess it's because of this? Any thoughts are appreciated!

From what I've understood, this is connected to two polygons being too close to each other and then generating a line. I also saw that the tool "v.clean" can be used to adjust this but still not sure how to use it (not which value to set - I saw somewhere 0.1). But even when using that, the output layer is different and I don't understand how to use aggregate later.

If you still recieve that error you can try either (or combinations of): Buffer with a very small distance, Snap to Grid and/or Simplify
